# What keyboard layout is this?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Can anyone help me identify this keyboard layout (it's on an Eee PC)? The problem is that it's AZERTY but with German Letters/words and as you know a German keyboard is QWERTY not AZERTY. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Encase you didn't know, I believe you can make your keyboard act like a qwerty through: Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language and changing your keyboard to US if you preferred.

Comment: I know the question 7 years old, but is this a joke? I would bet someone took the keys from an ordinary layout and swapped the keys around to make an AZERTY. Just look at the Num keys, the "0" should be below the "1" num key, not right of the "3" key, and the "Minus" sign should be right of the "3" num key, above the "+" num key. 

I mean, I could remove the keycaps of my keyboard, insert them in alphabetical order and ask, what layout this is... Or are we at puzzles and games?

Answer (score 1):

The layout for this keyboard is AZERTY, but just the layout is not enough. Each country can also have specific keys added or changed on a default layout.

For example both French and Belgium layouts frequently uses the AZERTY layout.

In your layout, there are german words present, but Germany usually uses a QWERTZ keyboard. For that reason I think the layout is switserland/azerty or austria/azerty

Comment: It's pretty close to Belgian, but not quite. Compare for example [Unicomp's idea of a Belgian 105-key keyboard layout](http://support.pckeyboard.com/knowledgebase.php?article=13).

Answer (score 0):

This is a German AZERTY keyboard layout, Difficult to find,[here is the download link](http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1452594), open rar file and run setup in \German azerty\layout01 folder, after finishing go to Control Panel\Language and you should find the new "Deutsch" keyboard.  if you have a similar case then you can download [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339), and check out video for help.